# Как получить массив только из нужного родительского класса?

Tags: javascript

Нужно получить массив элементов с классом.

```
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('class');
```

И получаю их со всей страницы,( они у меня есть в 3 секциах разных) однако мне надо их получить из одной секции. Секции имеют уникальные классы. Вопрос как получить только элемент которые дочерние для секции которая мне требуется

```
<section class='nr1'>
<div class='test'> test1</div>
<div class='test'> test2</div>
<div class='test'> test3</div>
<div class='test'> test4</div>
</section>

<section class='nr2'>
<div class='test'> test1</div>
<div class='test'> test2</div>
<div class='test'> test3</div>
<div class='test'> test4</div>
</section>

<section class='nr3'>
<div class='test'> test1</div>
<div class='test'> test2</div>
<div class='test'> test3</div>
<div class='test'> test4</div>
</section>
```

Как получить элементы с классом test из секции с классом nr3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```js
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.nr2 .test');
console.log(blocks.length);
for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  console.log(blocks[i].textContent);
}
```

```html
<section class='nr1'>
  <div class='test'> test1.1</div>
  <div class='test'> test1.2</div>
  <div class='test'> test1.3</div>
  <div class='test'> test1.4</div>
</section>


<section class='nr2'>
  <div class='test'> test2.1</div>
  <div class='test'> test2.2</div>
  <div class='test'> test2.3</div>
  <div class='test'> test2.4</div>
</section>


<section class='nr3'>
  <div class='test'> test3.1</div>
  <div class='test'> test3.2</div>
  <div class='test'> test3.3</div>
  <div class='test'> test3.4</div>
</section>
```

Или так:

```js
var section = document.getElementsByClassName('nr2')[0],
  blocks = section.querySelectorAll('.test');
console.log(blocks.length);
for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  console.log(blocks[i].textContent);
}
```

```html
<section class='nr1'>
  <div class='test'> test1.1</div>
  <div class='test'> test1.2</div>
  <div class='test'> test1.3</div>
  <div class='test'> test1.4</div>
</section>


<section class='nr2'>
  <div class='test'> test2.1</div>
  <div class='test'> test2.2</div>
  <div class='test'> test2.3</div>
  <div class='test'> test2.4</div>
</section>


<section class='nr3'>
  <div class='test'> test3.1</div>
  <div class='test'> test3.2</div>
  <div class='test'> test3.3</div>
  <div class='test'> test3.4</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое